# 3rd Party Gym environment registration with rllib: go-v0

Tags: python, openai-gym, ray

As a learning exercise to figure out how to use a custom Gym environment with rllib, I've set out to produce the simplest example possible of training against [GymGo](https://github.com/aigagror/GymGo).  So there's a [way to register a gym env with rllib](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rllib-env.html), but I'm going around in circles.

This is as far as I've gotten:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ray
import gym

from ray import tune
from ray.rllib.agents.ppo import PPOTrainer
from ray.tune.registry import register_env

ray.init()

def env_creator(env_name):
    from custom_gym.envs.gym_go import gym_go as env #THIS DOESNT WORK
    return env


env = env_creator('go-v0')
tune.register_env('goEnv', lambda: config, env(config))
tune.run(PPOTrainer, config={"env": "goEnv", "num_workers":18})
```

```
$ python3 raytest2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "raytest2.py", line 17, in <module>
    env = env_creator('go-v0')
  File "raytest2.py", line 13, in env_creator
    from custom_gym.envs.gym_go import gym_go as env
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'custom_gym'
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:  This appears to be an improvement, but more issues to work out

```py
import ray
from ray import tune
from ray.rllib.agents.ppo import PPOTrainer
from ray.tune.registry import register_env

ray.init()

def create_my_env():
  import gym
  return gym.make('gym_go:go-v0', size=7, reward_method='real')

env_creator = lambda config: create_my_env()
tune.register_env('go-v0', env_creator)
tune.run(PPOTrainer, config={"env": "go-v0", "num_workers":18})
```

Comment: You did not define custom_gym anywhere. Did you mean to use just gym? Or to modify the default gym setup and assign it to custom_gym?

Comment: @bobmcn I was using [this post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58551029/rllib-use-custom-registered-environments).  I am a bit baffled about where custom_gym came from.  In any case I haven't seen a really good example of the use of tune.register_env.  I also feel like I'm missing a few other pieces.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm trying to figure out how to use a 3rd party Gym environment, with Gym + Ray